# Multiple API request using componentDidMount and mapping

Tags: reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I have one API working properly for me, but I want to fetch add another api (https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches) to my current code and add it to my div table below.  I believe I should use `promise.all` but when I tried it, I kept getting "JSON is not a function" error or the screen would be blank. Also, I need to know is it possible to map more than one API? I know which props I want to add to the "const" in the "return" part not sure about the mapping.  Can someone please help?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    rockets: [],
    error: null
  };

  fetchRockets() {
    fetch(`https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          rockets: data,
          isLoading: false,
        })
      )
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchRockets();
  }
  render() {
    const { isLoading, rockets, error } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Rockets</h1>
        {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
        {!isLoading ? (
          rockets.map(rocket => {
            const { name, id,  first_flight, description } = rocket;
            return (
              <div key={name}>

<div className="Data-row">
      <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 divTableCell"><br />{name}</div>
      <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 divTableCell"><br />{id}</div>
      <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 divTableCell"><br />{first_flight}</div>
      <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 divTableCell"><br />{description}</div>
      <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 divTableCell"><a href="#hashLink">Expand</a></div>
      <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 divTableCell"><br /><div id="hashLink">I have expanded like a Pufferfish.<a href="#">collapse</a></div></div>
      

</div>            


    </div>
           


            );
          })
        ) : (
          <h3>Loading...</h3>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

}



export default App;
```

Comment: what is the value of `response.ok`?

Comment: Hi, umm I'm not sure sorry.

Comment: Code in the question appears to be the working code before adding the extra `fetch()`. Hard for anyone to make a judgement without seeing the non-working code.

Comment: If I wanted to add another fetch(api) how would I do so?